# Looking for a good web application deployment strategy (ASP.NET MVC3)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, version-control, deployment, msdeploy

I’m looking for a good deployment strategy for deploying a ASP.NET MVC3 application. What I imagine is that each deployment would be some kind of commit to a Source Management System in the sense that a deployment tool could automatically do the following:

1) Upon generating a deployment package (a commit) the tool would
    remember the state of my Web.Config file, the state of a folder of
    auto-generated scripts containing new database changed, the state of
    a folder of batch files that contain new tasks to be run on the
    server, the state of files specifying ISS settings changes, etc.

2) When I build a package the next time, the tool would know to only
    package the new script files, web.config changes, new batch files,
    new ISS settings since my last package

3) Apply the package unto my web application

I started looking into MS Deploy but it only seems to do number 3. I’ve been searching around for either an application that that does what I imagine or a strategy to combine some SMS and MS Deploy. I'm hoping that someone has already solved the problem I feel I have here. My last resort of course is to build the tool but again, that would be my last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Team Foundation Server? If so, TFS comes with tools to automate builds (including labeling code, running unit tests, deploying, et cetera.) Take a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181710(v=vs.80).aspx

TFS is not exactly easy to configure and get going but it's free if you are already using TFS.

If you are not using TFS, look for continuous integration tools like NAnt or TeamCity.

Comment: So far NAnt seems to be the best framework on which I can build the flexible and powerful deployment process of my dreams. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Have you used [Web Deploy](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/984/configure-site-for-web-deploy-publishing/) and the "Publish" feature under Build in Visual Studio?

You can set options for things like leaving the previous files on the server.

Your web.config file, do you mean the main one or one that already exists elsewhere on the server? Your web.config file should copy from your project to the server, or are there settings that are different when running locally vs server? If so, look at using transforms to modify web.config.

Comment: Yes I looked at Web Deploy and web.config transforms but all these just seem to automate deployment. That's only part of what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a strategy to manage packaging over time

Answer (score 1):

This is only a partial answer to #1 for you, but we looked for a long time on a migration tool that we liked... We ultimately found Migrator.Net: http://code.google.com/p/migratordotnet/

Doing this, you can turn db migrations into a batch command

Comment: I'm definitely considering Migration.NET for my next application. Maybe I need to be a Rails developer instead; they have the best tools.